# OnClick load php file into HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

Basically, here is what I have:

- 2 Main Tabs;
- 1 Main Tabs has 4 SubTabs;
- Each Tab needs to load code upon selection.

Here is the `Nav` code:

```
<div class="container-fluid mt-3">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills justify-content-center" id="tab-city" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="city-dr" data-toggle="tab" href="#droh" role="tab" aria-controls="droh" aria-selected="true">Drohobych</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" id="city-content">
        <div class="tab-pane show active" id="droh" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="city-dr">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills justify-content-center" id="table-content" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item mt-2">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="droh-repair" data-toggle="tab" href="#droh-repairs" role="tab" aria-controls="droh-repairs" aria-selected="true">Repair</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="table-dr-fttb-pull-in" role="tab">FTTB Pull In</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content" id="table-content">
                <div class="tab-pane show active" id="droh-repairs" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="city-dr">
                    <?php
                    include(__DIR__ . '/tables/dr/table_dr_repair.php');
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

This is the code that I am trying to include:

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../headers/navbar.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../db/db_handler.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../util/constants.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../util/util.php');
?>

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Street</th>
        <th scope="col">Phone</th>
        <th scope="col">Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Price</th>
        <th scope="col">Comment</th>
        <th scope="col">Operator</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php
    $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM `" . Tables::$table_dr_fttb_pull_in . "` ORDER BY `date` DESC");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();


    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        print_task_details_as_table_row($row);
    }
    ?>

</table>
```

The problem is - nothing happens when the Tab is selected.
What I could do - simply get all the code from the file and insert it into HTML page.
However, I am not really fan of that solution since doing that for 7 more subtabs will result into one gigantic page with lots of repetitive code.

That's why I would rather do it this way.
How do I load the content when the tab is pressed?
Perhaps there is even a better way to handle this, so please help me figure this out.

Comment: AJAX is the answer to all your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here...

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Basic Example

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "/path/to/file",
  success: function(data){
   console.log(data);
 }
});
```

If you are trying to submit a form just add an AJAX data field...

```
var input1 = $('#input1').val();
var input2 = $('#input2').val();
$.ajax({
  method: "POST", //Method either GET or POST
  url: "/path/to/file.php", //Enter path to PHP file
  data: {
    "name1": input1, //Defining POST variables.
    "name2": input2
  },
  success: function(data){
   console.log(data); //Outputs data to the console
  }
)};
```

To retrieve the values in the php file, just simply use your type of method followed by the variable name. `$_POST['name1']` and/or `$_POST['name2']`

If you are not using jQuery, there is an alternative to using the Fetch()-API. Read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API.

Comment: Okay, I managed to figure this out. Now it works as intended, however, I want to avoid using a different ajax function for each of the tables that I need, but instead somehow make it reusable. Is there any way I can pass into my function what tab is currently selected?

Comment: Why not use the native fetch()-api instead of including a 87kb-bloated library like jQuery to make the ajax requests?

Comment: ^ I second this. Here's a link to help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: @MagnusEriksson great advice. I just tried fetch and got it working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: perhaps one of you could help me out how can I determine which tab was clicked when executing this script?

Comment: You could use a simple JS function such as $('#id-of-button').on('click', function(e){ ...(AJAX) ... } - Is this what is meant?